# Is it possible to determine if a scroll event was emitted by content height changing vs manual user input?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to ascertain if it's possible to determine whether a scroll event was emitted simply due to a height change of an element, as opposed to a manual user scroll?

We are utilizing an internally developed UI library which displays a "toast" message on the page until it detects any user interaction, in this case, they have the following event listeners hooked up:

```
document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClose);
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleClose);
document.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleClose);
```

Unfortunately, if we dispatch one of these toast messages and then asynchronously load any content which changes the page size, a scroll event is emitted regardless of whether a user has actually scrolled or not.  I've considered disabling the event from propagating, but we still would like a manual scroll to dismiss the toast message.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can check [`Event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted), but note that this is true if the scroll event is triggered by code like `window.scrollBy`.

Comment: Unfortunately Event.isTrusted is showing as true, so it looks like this won't help.  Thanks for the suggestion, though, @HereticMonkey!

Comment: Well it's ugly and hackish and all that. You could set a flag for your async content loads that you can check in your scroll handler to basically "ignore" the event if the flag is set. So the flow looks like this: set flag, async load content, unset flag in the async done.

Comment: @gforce301 -- I like the creativity, though I think this will be a last resort solution :)!